# exchengable correlation for unbalanced data in Generalized Estimating Equations

Tags: r

[image: example from Hardin and Hilbe book]
I am having a challenge in calculating the n_i(number of repeated measures) for unbalanced data. In the following example, the n_i is 4. Therefore calculating the denominator as shown in the book of Hardin and Hilbe, it is n_i(n_i-1) which is 4(4-1)=12. How do I calculate the same for unbalanced data?

```
 id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
    t <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
    y <- c(4,5,6,7,5,6,7,8)
    x <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
    xb <- c(5.5, 6.5, 5.5, 6.5, 5.5, 6.5, 5.5, 6.5)
    res <- c(-1.5, -1.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.5, 1.5)
    p3b <- data.frame(id, t, y, x, xb, res)
    gaussgee <- geeglm(y ~ x, id=id, corstr="exchangeable",
    family=gaussian, data=p3b)
    summary(gaussgee)
```

my unbalanced data example

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
    t <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3)
    y <- c(4,5,6,7,5,6,7)
    x <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

i figure this out

```
 res_total_n_for_alph<-df1 %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(y2 = sum(combn(y, 2, FUN = prod)),n = n())%>%  mutate(sampl_n = n*(n-1)/2)
  res_total_n_for_alph 
  #head(df1)
  
  sum_res_alpha<-sum(res_total_n_for_alph$y2)
  sum_res_alpha
  sum_n_alpha<-sum(res_total_n_for_alph$sampl_n)
  sum_n_alpha
  alpha<-(1/new.phi)*(1/(sum_n_alpha-r))*sum_res_alpha
  alpha
```